# In Express JS, post() method is working perfectly in firebase cloud function after deploying but not working in local machine

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, post

[image]I have one post() and get() request in Express JS. My post() request is not working in local machine.It is throwing 404 error and message **"Cannot POST /sendMessages/"**.However, when I deploy the app to the firebase cloud function and tested the requests both are working perfect. So, every time when I made changes I had to deploy and then test which is a tedious task.

```
    const functions = require("firebase-functions");    
    const express = require('express');
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    var cors = require('cors')
    const PORT = 3000;
    const app = express()
app.use(express.json())

app.use(cors())

app.get('/hello', (req, res, next) => {
    res.send('Welcome')
})

app.post('/sendMessages', (req, res) => {

    console.log(req.body)
res.json({ 'status': 'Success' })
})

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log("Server is running on port, " + PORT)
})

exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app)
```

Can anyone please tell me what's the issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think there's enough information here to help. Define "not working".

Comment: Thanks @DaveNewton for your quick response. I have updated my question. When I sent a post request from the local machine using postman. I am getting 404 error and message saying Cannot POST /sendMessages/

Comment: I cannot duplicate this locally (although I'd try removing the trailing slash from your request; I had a failure once with it, and it worked every time after that).

Comment: That's strange. But I am getting the same error. I have added the screenshot to the question. Can you @DaveNewton please check if I am doing anything wrong in postman?

Comment: Works fine for me including your JSON payload, duping as much of the request as I can. Are you sure you're running the server you think you are on 3000?

Comment: Have you disabled any local firewall to allow incoming http requests on localhost?  For example, on Windows, the default configuration of Windows Defender does not allow incoming http requests, even if originating from the same host.  You should also be logging errors on your server in case the `.listen()` isn't working correctly.

Comment: @DaveNewton Yes my server is running on the port 3000. I have been checking the get('/hello') in the browser and it's working fine on local host.

Comment: @jfriend00 Yes, I have disabled my firewall. Will there be any problem on incoming requests if I disable the firewall?

Comment: Not if you properly disabled it and there's nothing else running/blocking port 3000.

Comment: My point was that you might not be running the version of the server you think you are, e.g., if you modified the server code and didn't stop any existing server before starting the new code. There's really nothing here in the code that would prevent this from working.

Comment: @DaveNewton I tried hitting again after restarting the server, still it's not working.

Comment: Again, I don't believe there's enough information here to help. The code, as-is, with some package futzing to get it to run, is working fine for me.

Comment: Thank you so much @DaveNewton , jfriend00 for taking time and trying to find out the issue. I might be doing some silly mistake somewhere, will try to figure it out and will let you know if I am able to do it.

Comment: Good luck--hope you work it out!

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I figured out what silly mistake I have been doing all these days. I was running my nodemon start on normal folder rather than functions folder.